# Android: Accessing file system from C programs

Tags: security, directory, filesystems, native, android-ndk

Does anyone know which directories are accessible for reading/writing from the native applications(C code)? I can create files in /data/data/mydir but not in /data/mydir.
The /sdcard is not accessible in anyway from c.
I appreciate all help/info/links to info etc.

Comment: obviously this is not allowed due to the android security model.